# Timing of pikuach nefesh

Tags: halacha, pikuachnefesh-danger-life

What is the halacha on how *imminent* the danger of death has to be for you to be allowed to invoke pikuach nefesh and break a commandment to save a life?

Obviously if someone is drowning before your eyes and you can save him by breaking a commandment (without seriously endangering your own life), you do it.  But what if the danger is, say, exposure to radiation that will cause cancer 20 years later?

I know that in cases of uncertainty on whether a life is really at risk, you err on the side of offering assistance. [Yoma 8:6]  But here I am asking about timing, not uncertainty.  Any sources?

Comment: I know the poskim discuss eating on Yom kippur for a person where they wouldn't die on Yom Kippur, but they might have complications which could end up being fatal. But that's still a direct consequence. I think that's really a factor which you should be considering: how much is a time element, and how much is a direct consequence. it could be that 20 years is not called pikuach nefesh (if it's not) because it's a long time away; or because lots of factors could cause cancer in 20 years, and it's not clearly a  directly consequence of the radiation.

Comment: I'd say, if you are to err on the side of offering assistance in the case of an uncertainty (death _might_ occur _soon_), so much more so should you err (if it is even considered erring) on the side of offering assistance in the case of a delayed certainty (death _will_ occur, but a lot _later_). There still would be a question regarding a situation of delayed uncertainty (death _might_ occur, and even then, only a lot _later_).

Comment: @TamirEvan -- "err ... on the side of offering assistance in the case of a delayed certainty (death will occur, but a lot later). "  It is never "certain".  What if a cure for cancer is found ten years later?